# Помогите с реализацией

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Я учусь работать на движке libgdx (и box2d соответственно) и хочу реализовать следующее. У меня есть персонаж, и я хочу, чтобы при его движении за ним оставался хвост, который будет домажить врагов, постепенно появляться, иметь определённую максимальную длину и постепенно пропадать, когда персонаж останавливается. Также, я хочу, чтобы этот хвост повторял путь персонажа, то есть, если персонаж прошёлся по квадрату в исходную точку, то и хвост бы изобразил квадрат, если ему хватает длины. Думаю мне понадобится отслеживать пересечение хвоста с самим собой. Не представляю, как мне это сделать при помощи box2d, направьте на правильный путь, пожалуйста.

Comment: может быть хранить информацию о том где прямоугольник был последние 10 кадров?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Звучит интересно, но тогда мне придётся вручную отслеживать коллизии

Comment: ну иметь их 10 и позиционировать в соответствии с 10 последними кадрами

Comment: @StrangerintheQ да, звучит разумно, спасибо